# Calling microsoft graph api returns with 'InvalidAuthenticationToken' error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

This is how I exchange the OBO token:

```
    public static async Task<string> ExchangeForOBOToken(ExchangeOBORequest request)
    {
        var contentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        contentData.Add("client_id", request.client_id);
        contentData.Add("client_secret", request.client_secret);
        contentData.Add("requested_token_use", request.requested_token_use);
        contentData.Add("grant_type", request.grant_type);
        contentData.Add("scope", request.scope);
        contentData.Add("assertion", request.assertion);

        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        using var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(contentData);
        content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

        var res=  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return res;
    }
```

And after that I get this response which is valid:
[image]

After trying to call 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/' in postman with Bearer token set to the access token I got back from the OBO Exchange I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-04-01T11:19:36",
            "request-id": "0cbe8050-1113-4ea9-ab6c-41feafe08d73",
            "client-request-id": "0cbe8050-1113-4ea9-ab6c-41feafe08d73"
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call it in postman:

[image]

Comment: What scopes are you using?

Comment: You are using Teams tab provided token to call Graph API(scope: api//domain/appid/access_as_user). It will not work. You need to generate On behalf of token with Graph API permissions as scope. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: @Wet_Pantz - Could you please confirm if your issue has been resolved?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT still haven't resolved it, I don't have time right now. Tomorrow I will reply back.